# Transforming partial derivatives to polar coordinates

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, polar-coordinates

I have to convert the following expression $V(x,y) = x\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} - y\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ to polar coordinates. How do i express the partial derivatives in terms of $r$ and $\theta$? The answer should be something like $V(r,\theta) = \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial \theta}$, where $F(r,\theta) = f(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP is rightfully using a different notation for the function
depending on which coordinates it depends on: $f(x,y)$ vs. $F(r,\theta)\,.$

By the chain rule,

\begin{align}
\partial_rF&=(\cos\theta)\,\partial_xf+(\sin\theta)\,\partial_yf\,,\\[2mm]
\tfrac1r\partial_\theta F&=(-\sin\theta)\,\partial_xf+(\cos\theta)\,\partial_yf\,.
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
\partial_xf&=(\cos\theta)\,\partial_rF+(-\sin\theta)\,\tfrac1r\partial_\theta F\,,\\[2mm]
\partial_yf&=(\sin\theta)\,\partial_rF+(\cos\theta)\,\tfrac1r\partial_\theta F\,.
\end{align}
Then,
\begin{align}\require{cancel}
&x\,\partial_yf-y\,\partial_xf\\[2mm]
&=\cancel{(r\cos\theta\sin\theta)\,\partial_rF}+(\cos^2\theta)\,\partial_\theta F-\cancel{(r\sin\theta\cos\theta)\,\partial_rF}+(\sin^2\theta)\,\partial_\theta F\\[2mm]
&=\partial_\theta F\,.\tag{1}
\end{align}

Another approach is to consider the one-form
$$
x\,dy-y\,dx
$$
that is the dual of the vector field $x\,\partial_y-y\,\partial_x\,.$
Using the chain rule in the form
$$
dx=(\cos\theta)\,dr-(r\sin\theta)\,d\theta\,,\quad dy=(\sin\theta)\,dr+(r\cos\theta)\,d\theta\tag{2}
$$
gives
\begin{align}\require{cancel}
&x\,dy-y\,dx\\[2mm]
&=\cancel{(r\cos\theta)(\sin\theta)\,dr}+(r^2\cos^2\theta)\,d\theta-\cancel{(r\sin\theta)(\cos\theta)\,dr}+(r^2\sin^2\theta)\,d\theta\\[2mm]
&=r^2\,d\theta\,.\tag{3}
\end{align}
The factor $r^2$ seems odd but it is correct because the vector
$x\,\partial_y-y\,\partial_x=\partial_\theta$ has length $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=r\,.$ From (2) we see that the covector $r\,d\theta$ has length one. Therefore $r^2\,d\theta$ has length $r$ as it must.

- It follows that the vector that corresponds to $r^2\,d\theta$ is $\partial_\theta\,.$

This is compatible with the metric in polar coordinates being
$$
\boldsymbol{g}=dr\otimes dr+r^2\,d\theta\otimes d\theta
$$
and the musical isomorphism by which
$$
\partial_\theta{}^\flat=\boldsymbol{g}(\partial_\theta\,,\,.\,)=r^2\,d\theta\,.
$$

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Write $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ and apply the chain rule \begin{equation}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}\end{equation}

We can substitute $\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}=-r\sin\theta= -y$
and $\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}=r\cos\theta=x$

Therefore \begin{equation}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}=-y\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+x\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=V(x,y)\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

By the chain rule:

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}$

Which can be expressed as a matrix.

$\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} \\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta} \\ \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial r} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\end{pmatrix}$

The matrix's inverse can be used to do a reverse coordinate transform without having to reuse the chain rule.

You can effectively bypass the coordinate transform or much calculation at all.

$V(x,y)=x \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}-y\frac{\partial f}{\partial x }=\vec{r} \cdot (\nabla f \times \hat{k})$

The term in parentheses is obviously perpendicular to $\hat{k}$. That means it only has $\hat{\theta} $ and $\hat{r}$ components. $\vec{r}$ has no $\hat{\theta}$ component in polar coordinates. It follows that only the $\hat{r}$ component of the term in parentheses plays a role. $\hat{k}$ is the normal to the plane, so up to a sign it just swaps x for y coordinates, or r for theta coordinates. This means the only useful term in parentheses is $\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}\hat{r}$.Since $\vec{r} = r \hat{r}$ then the dot product is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}$ establishing the desired result.